# Does Azure vnet peering support traffic passing through multiple virtual appliances that reside in the Hub vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

[Hub and Spoke vnet peering with two virtual appliances in the Hub vnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXvG6.png)

As shown in the above linked diagram, when the client (vnet A) needs to ping server (vnet C), is it possible to force that traffic to go through the two appliances inside the Hub vnet (vnet B)?

UDR1 forces traffic to go through Virtual Appliance Router 1, and UDR2 forces traffic out from Router 1 to Router 2, once traffic comes out of Router 2, it will arrive at server, this is done via peering itself.

UDR3 and UDR4 are for return traffic.

tcpdump on Router 1 shows traffic coming in, and then Router 1 forwards that traffic out to Router 2, but there is no traffic seen on Router 2, despite UDR 2.

However, pinging from client to server does work, this means Azure is doing the delivery, which causes the traffic to bypass Router 2.

Is multiple virtual appliances supported in a peered vnet environment? It is supported when all traffic is within the same vnet, this is tested working.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported. VNet peering doesn't impose any additional restrictions. I'd recommend using Network Watcher connectivity troubleshoot to check what the issue is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-portal

Are you using the two appliances as proxy? Is there a reason both ingress and egress traffic needs to go through the two appliances? Do you have a load balancer in play?

Comment: Thanks! I just saw this. The use case was using a load balancer to load balance FW's. I got it to work, the issue I had previously was that I summarized the routes, instead of having two specific routes that correspond to the subnets being created in the vnet, I used 0.0.0.0/0.